# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
const deletePerson = (persons) => {
axios
  .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${persons.name}`)
  .then(console.log(`done`))
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(setPersons(Object.values(persons).filter(q => q.name !== false)))}
```

I am a newbie in React.js.
I have a problem, which I have been trying to solve for a couple of days.
I added the Button for Delete requests, and in the different ways, it returns the same type of mistake:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name').

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UTAv.png)

the use-case in that I am using this Button inside the resulting method, which automatically filters the list of persons:

```
const Filter = (props) => {return (<> {props.persons.filter(person => person.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.showFiltered.toLowerCase())).map((filteredName, id) => (
    <li key={id.toString()}>
      {filteredName.name} {filteredName.number} <Button text='delete' handleClick={props.deletePerson} />
    </li>  
  ))}  
</>)}
```

Comment: Can you console and share the `persons` object ?

Comment: {
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Arto Hellas",
      "number": "040-123456",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "number": "39-44-5323523",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Dan Abramov",
      "number": "12-43-234345",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "Mary Poppendieck",
      "number": "39-23-6423122",
      "id": 4
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Please add a code as text instead of an image

Comment: You have provided a JSON array. You cannot access persons.name from json array.  You have to filter and send the persons name.

Comment: Can you explain the usecase ?

Comment: I added the code, where I showed that I nested the Button inside the Filtering (total) method, which shows the result when the user wants to filter the names inside the list and delete the person from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might occurred because it was a failed request since you didn't pass anything to `deletePersons` function.

```
const Filter = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.persons
        .filter((person) =>
          person.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.showFiltered.toLowerCase())
        )
        .map((filteredName, id) => (
          <li key={id.toString()}>
            {filteredName.name} {filteredName.number}
            <Button text="delete" handleClick={() => props.deletePerson(props.persons)} />
          </li>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using array values based on the entire object and not the persons value inside the object. And from the looks of it you are trying to find a name with the value false which doesn't seem to match what you have there.

Something like this is probably what you are looking for

```
.then(setPersons(Object.values(personsList).filter(q => q.name !== persons.name)))}
```

Comment: it still gives the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name') 
   I understand that the problem is deeper, I will dig further.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** (Updated)

```js
const deletePerson = (persons) => {
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${persons.persons.name}`)
    .then(console.log(`done`))
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .then(() => setPersons(persons["persons"].filter((q) => q.name !== false)));
};
```

**Explanation:**

Using `Object.values(persons)` will return nested array which look something like this:

```
[
  [
    { "name": "Arto Hellas", "number": "040-123456", "id": 1 },
    { "name": "Ada Lovelace", "number": "39-44-5323523", "id": 2 },
    { "name": "Dan Abramov", "number": "12-43-234345", "id": 3 },
    { "name": "Mary Poppendieck", "number": "39-23-6423122", "id": 4 }
  ]
]
```

However, you're expecting `q` variable to be:

```json
[
  { "name": "Arto Hellas", "number": "040-123456", "id": 1 },
  { "name": "Ada Lovelace", "number": "39-44-5323523", "id": 2 },
  { "name": "Dan Abramov", "number": "12-43-234345", "id": 3 },
  { "name": "Mary Poppendieck", "number": "39-23-6423122", "id": 4 }
]
```

Therefore, there are two ways of fixing this:

1. Extracting the nested array
   `Object.values(persons)` => `Object.values(persons)[0]`
2. Access the object value directly
   `Object.values(persons)` => `persons["persons"]`

Comment: .then(setPersons(persons['persons'].filter((q) => q.name !== persons.name)))       It gives the error: App.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at deletePerson (App.js:94:1)

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you run the code again?

Comment: Also, can you show me the logs of this code?

Comment: `const deletePerson = (persons) => {console.log(persons)}`

Comment: SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: button, …}

Comment: I've tried ..persons["persons"].. same issue: App.js:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Comment: Can you upload your code to some kind of sandbox like `jsfiddle` or something? That would make it easier to find the bug.